# Restoring backup of AdventureWorks2017 on Linux SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

I have found myself in a very strange situation: what used to work before does not work anymore.

I'm trying to restore an `Adventureworks` backup on a SQL Server running on an Ubuntu machine with this T-SQL code:

```
RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks2017
FROM DISK = '/home/sergey/AW/AdventureWorks2017.bak'
WITH MOVE 'AdventureWorks2017' TO '/home/sergey/AW/AdventureWorks2017.mdf',
     MOVE 'AdventureWorks2017_log' TO '/home/sergey/AW/AdventureWorks2017_log.ldf'
GO
```

But I'm getting an error:

> [S0001][3142] File "AdventureWorks2017" cannot be restored over the existing "/home/sergey/AW/AdventureWorks2017.mdf". Reissue the RESTORE statement using WITH REPLACE to overwrite pre-existing files, or WITH MOVE to identify an alternate location.

This blog post seem to talk about a similar issue, but the recipes mentioned does not work.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message states, that the target file already exists.

Try

```
RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks2017
FROM DISK = '/home/sergey/AW/AdventureWorks2017.bak'
WITH MOVE 'AdventureWorks2017' TO '/home/sergey/AW/AdventureWorks2017.mdf',
     MOVE 'AdventureWorks2017_log' TO '/home/sergey/AW/AdventureWorks2017_log.ldf',
     REPLACE
GO
```

The full documentation for the RESTORE Transact-SQL command can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: Thank you very much, cannot express enough gratitude to your saving me!!!